# Context juggling in PyCUDA to create store parameters in different GPU memory

Tags: pycuda

I'm trying to juggle the context in the different GPUs to store different parameters in different GPUs. So what I have done is to initialize cuda, set the device, create the context (`ctx1`) for the device, then use `curandom` to generate a GPUarray of random values. After which I pop the context and follow the same steps, set it to another device, create a new context and generate another GPUarray of random values. So from what I understand, my `x1` is stored in the memory of GPU1 and `x2` is stored in the memory of GPU2. However, I realised that when I `.pop()` and `.push()` `ctx1` and `ctx2` respectively and vice versa, I am still able to access both `x1` and `x2`. Is thus due to the Unified Virtual Addressing or enable peer access that allows me to access both `x1` and `x2` regardless of which context I'm in?

```
import pycuda
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.curandom as curandom

d = 2 ** 15

cuda.init()
dev1 = cuda.Device(1)
ctx1 = dev1.make_context()

curng1 = curandom.XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator()

x1 = curng1.gen_normal((d,d), dtype = np.float32) # so x1 is stored in GPU 1     


ctx1.pop() # clearing ctx of GPU1

dev2 = cuda.Device(1)
ctx2 = dev2.make_context()

curng2 = curandom.XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator()

x2 = curng2.gen_normal((d,d), dtype = np.float32) # so x2 is stored in GPU 2
```

Comment: "I am still able to access both x1 and x2" - access how? You should specify what functions you are calling.